# Powershell: Cannot bind parameter 'PercentComplete'. Cannot convert value "GetPercent" to type "System.Int32"

Tags: powershell

I am newbie in powershell and I'm trying to write a progress activity.

First I created a function:

```
function GetPercent($current, $total) {
    return ($current/$total) * 100
}
```

and then write

```
[Int32]$steps = 10

Write-Progress -Activity "Compile BLABLA project" -Status "Compiling and deploying BLABLA" -PercentComplete GetPercent(1, $steps)
```

and I got error:

> Write-Progress : Cannot bind parameter 'PercentComplete'. Cannot
>   convert value "GetPercent" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input
>   string was not in a correct format."

I tried

```
function GetPercent($current, $total) {
    return ($current/$total) * 100 -as [Int32]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell, calls to functions are space-separated, not comma separated. Change your code to

```
Write-Progress -Activity "Compile BLABLA project" -Status "Compiling and deploying BLABLA" -PercentComplete (GetPercent 1 $steps)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap the last parameter in parenthesis: `-PercentComplete (GetPercent 1, $steps)`

There are some nice tutorials how to add a progress bar to your PoSh scripts, e.g. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/29/add-a-progress-bar-to-your-powershell-script/

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\
For($i = 1; $i -le $files.count; $i++)
{ Write-Progress -Activity "Collecting files" -status "Finding file $i" `
-percentComplete ($i / $files.count*100)}
$files | Select name
```

or https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/perfect-progress-bars-for-powershell/